# Why are binary numbers sometimes written with one or more leading zeros that don't change the number (quantity) represented?

Tags: notation, binary

Binary numbers like '0110', or '00100101' are seen very often in all contexts. What are the leading (left hand side) zeroes for? Why did the writer not write '110' and '100101', respectively?

Answer (score 2):

Leading zeroes in binary usually indicate the bit length of the data type.
For example, the number `110` represented in a 4 bit data type would be `0110`.
Even if there is no data type specified, it's sometimes common to pad your binary numbers to the next power of 2. For example, `10111` of size 5 should be padded to 8 $(2^3)$ as `00010111`

Comment: You wrote: "Even if there is no data type specified, it's sometimes common to pad your binary numbers to the next power of 2." What is the rationale for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Depend on context, so, I bring one small example: if we consider $3$-bit field, then $110$ is negative in  $2$'s complement and equal $-2$, while in $4$-bit field $0110$ is positive and equal $6$ in same $2$'s complement.

Comment: What makes 110 negative? The leading '1'?

Comment: Yes. In $2$'s complement all binary code with leading bit $1$ is negative.